# PIXI.JS - Graphics.drawCircle() + animation seems to have some issues

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

So i decided to start playing around with Pixi.js today and everything was fine up to the point where i wanted to draw more than 780 circles.

```
<script>
    var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xffffff);
        var container = new PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer();
    var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, {antialias: true});

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

    requestAnimFrame(animate);

    stage.addChild(container);

        var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
        graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        graphics.alpha = 0.05;

        var circleCountCurrent = 0;
        var circleCountMax = 1000; //781;

        var angle = 0;
        var anglSpeed = 0.025;

        var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        var circleSize = 10;

        var xPos = 100;
        var xSpeed = 0.5;
        var amplitude = 20;

        container.addChild(graphics);


    function animate() 
        {
         requestAnimFrame(animate);

              var yPos; 

              if(circleCountCurrent < circleCountMax)
              {
                    yPos = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * amplitude;
                    drawCircle(xPos, yPos, circleSize);

                    angle += anglSpeed;
                    xPos += xSpeed;

                    circleCountCurrent++;

                    //console.log('xPos: ' + xPos);
              }

         renderer.render(stage);
    }

        function drawCircle(x, y, r)
        {
              graphics.drawCircle(x, y, r);
        }
</script>
```

This is my code (no, it's not super elegant...) and i'm trying to figure out what is wrong. I just want the wave to continue across the screen and not start from the initial xPos after 780+ iterations like this:

[image]

Notice the line that goes from the end of the wave back to the beginning. It appears after 780+ iterations

I'm using pixi.js v2.2.8 if this helps.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Have a great day!

/ André

Comment: Have you tested this on other machines? If you move the whole thing up, does the line stay in place or does it move with it?

Comment: I tried it on another desktop system and the result was the same except for IE (11) where the line going back to the start is missing. I also removed the wave calculations so it just draws the circles in a straight line and the result still not as intended.
I did try it on a iphone5s - chrome 41.0.2272.56 - and there it works as intended.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the graphics cards or WebGL/Canvas implementations then.

Comment: OK. I'll post the link to this page on the PIXI forum and see if they have some more insight into this. 
Thanks for your time Mike, appreciate it. :)

Comment: Potentially related: https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/1076